# Change SQL Server default TCP port running in Docker container

Tags: docker, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2016

I create one docker container running SQL Server 2014 image. SQL server is running on default port 1433. Now on same server i create another container having same sql server image. Now I can only able to access 1st container from outside the server which is running on port 1433 but other new container is only accessible inside the server where container is running. I am not able to access container 2 sql server from outside the server.
If i can change TCP port of sql server running in container 2 then i may able to access the sql server from outside servers.

If there is any other work around then please help.

Comment: Docker doesn't run SQL Server 2014. The earliest SQL Server version you can run docker in is 2017.

Comment: In regards to changing the port, see [Change the TCP port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf?view=sql-server-2017#tcpport). if you want to have a different port on the host map to 1433 on the container, see [Run multiple SQL Server containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-2017#run-multiple-sql-server-containers) which explains a bit on this.

Comment: You can specify the external port for access outside the container by mapping the port with the `-p` run command parameter (e.g. `-p 14333:1433` will allow you to connect externally using port 14333.

Comment: @Larnu, one can run earlier SQL Server versions in a Windows container but it needs to be a custom image and it's not officially supported. I run a custom SQL Server 2012 image as part of a build process.